# What does "data-lite" mean as an advantage of an application?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "data-lite" mean in the following context?

> This application is:
>
> ...
>
> - data-lite and saves you money
>
> ...

I couldn't find it online or in the dictionary (OAAD). For more context, I read it in the description of [this application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.binu.platform.android.binu).

Comment: Please add a link to source, or some more context

Comment: @jwpat7: edited.

Answer (score 2):

*Lite* has a dictionary entry:

> *adjective*
>   denoting a low-fat or low-sugar version of a manufactured food or drink product:
>      *lite beer*
>      • *informal* denoting a simpler or less challenging version of a particular thing or person:
>         *I am the happy feminist who likes men, the feminist lite*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lite)

"Data-lite" follows the form of "feminist lite" in the example: a product which does not transmit or consume much data. I would guess that the application is something like a mobile phone app where data transmission may be chargeable: being data-lite saves on transmission costs.

["Lite beer" is neither low-fat nor low-sugar, of course, but low-alcohol. Another faulty example in ODO.]

Answer (score 2):

A light application is one which loads fast, works fast and doesn't use much of the bandwidth. Data-lite, I suppose, is a fancy way of saying that the application is light.

Comment: would be further more appropriate if you add..
works fast and doesn't use much of the system resources or bandwidth..

Comment: I think more precisely, it means that the application does not store (or perhaps use) a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

The OED has the following entry for *lite*:

> ORIGIN 1950s: a commercial respelling of light.

The same source defines lite:

> • informal denoting a simpler or less challenging version of a particular thing or person: *I am the happy feminist who likes men, the feminist lite.*

I suspect in your case *data-lite* would be something that is lightweight and fast as opposed to heavy and slow.

Answer (score 0):

As others have touched on, the specific meaning of *data-lite and saves you money* in this instance is that it requires a comparatively small quantity of transmitted data (for an application of its type, one presumes), and therefore will cost you less to run while disconnected from a wifi network and thus consuming mobile data bandwidth. It is a property that I would consider attractive in an smartphone app specification.

Similarly, text-only web browsers were popular in the dial-up days of the 90's and early 00's for the same reason, although often because the time taken to load a webpage which you knew would contain images that you would find irrelevant, such as any cinema's movie listings, would threaten your sanity more than your pocket.